# Setting restrictedToMinimumLevel per sink in appSettings

Tags: appsettings, serilog

Not sure if this is supported, but I would like to set the 'restrictedToMinimumLevel' for my ColoredConsole sink via appSettings.

I am creating the Serilog global object as follows:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadAppSettings()
                .CreateLogger();
```

I tried the following in my app.config:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:ColoredConsole.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Information" />
```

It seems Serilog is trying to process but chokes on the string to Serilog.Events.LogLevel enum(?) conversion.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel'.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this functionality not currently supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, so in all likelihood you've found a bug. I've [raised one](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/164) on the Serilog issue tracker for it, if possible I'll get a fix out soon.

Comment: This is fixed, as of Serilog 1.3.35.